# How to rotate images automatically

Tags: jquery, html, css

How to rotate images automatically? please check my fiddle, I'm trying to change image automatically with out any click event please check this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/hu3v8/1/

```
<div id="slider-code">
    <div class="viewport">
        <ul class="overview">
            <li><img src="http://www.baijs.nl/tinycarousel/images/picture3.jpg" /></li>
            <li><img src="http://www.baijs.nl/tinycarousel/images/picture2.jpg" /></li>
            <li><img src="http://www.baijs.nl/tinycarousel/images/picture1.jpg" /></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <a class="buttons next" id="nextButton" href="#">right</a>
</div>
```

Comment: What do you actually mean by _I'm trying to change image automatically with out any click event_? using `setInterval`?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/hu3v8/210/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try with the below link.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NzCAZ/11/)

```
$("#slideshow > div:gt(0)").hide();

setInterval(function() {
    $('#slideshow > div:first')
        .fadeOut(1500)
        .next()
        .fadeIn(1500)
        .end()
        .appendTo('#slideshow');
}, 2000);
```

Answer (score 4):

http://baijs.com/tinycarousel/

The `tinycarousel` plugin you have used is already providing animated example

please make use of option `interval` and `intervalTime`

```js
$(function() {

  var current = 1;
  var totalImages = $("#slider-code li").size();
  var oSlider = $('#slider-code').tinycarousel({
    animation: true,
    controls: false,
    interval: true, // set interval option
    intervalTime: 1000 // 1 second
  });

  $('#nextButton').click(function() {
    current += 1;
    if (current > totalImages) {
      current = 1;
    }
    oSlider.tinycarousel_move(current);
  });
});
```

```css
#slider-code {
  height: 125px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
#slider-code .viewport {
  float: left;
  width: 240px;
  height: 125px;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}
#slider-code .buttons {
  display: block;
  margin: 30px 10px 0 0;
  float: left;
}
#slider-code .next {
  margin: 30px 0 0 10px;
}
#slider-code .disable {
  visibility: hidden;
}
#slider-code .overview {
  list-style: none;
  position: absolute;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
}
#slider-code .overview li {
  float: left;
  margin: 0 20px 0 0;
  padding: 1px;
  height: 121px;
  border: 1px solid #dcdcdc;
  width: 236px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://baijs.com/tinycarousel/js/jquery.tinycarousel.js"></script>

<div id="slider-code">

  <div class="viewport">
    <ul class="overview">
      <li>
        <img src="http://www.baijs.nl/tinycarousel/images/picture3.jpg" />
      </li>
      <li>
        <img src="http://www.baijs.nl/tinycarousel/images/picture2.jpg" />
      </li>
      <li>
        <img src="http://www.baijs.nl/tinycarousel/images/picture1.jpg" />
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <a class="buttons next" id="nextButton" href="#">right</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

```js
$("#slideshow > div:gt(0)").hide();

setInterval(function() {
  $('#slideshow > div:first')
    .fadeOut(1000)
    .next()
    .fadeIn(1000)
    .end()
    .appendTo('#slideshow');
}, 3000);
```

```css
#slideshow {
  margin: 50px auto;
  position: relative;
  width: 240px;
  height: 240px;
  padding: 10px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
}
#slideshow > div {
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  left: 10px;
  right: 10px;
  bottom: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="slideshow">
  <div>
    <img src="//farm6.static.flickr.com/5224/5658667829_2bb7d42a9c_m.jpg">
  </div>
  <div>
    <img src="//farm6.static.flickr.com/5230/5638093881_a791e4f819_m.jpg">
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Nice one, This should be the answer rather than plugins.

Comment: @RohitArora OP is already using `tinycarousel` plugin, if OP started from scratch, this would be a perfect answer.

Answer (score -1):

Do you mean a slider like this?

[Jssor Slider](http://www.jssor.com/demos/image-slider.html)